# Need my entry price to be a set % less than EMA and a set % higher for exit price, e.g 10%. Percentage to be taken from EMA

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Another condition for my entry order is that the EMA must be smaller than MA but the price must be a certain percentage smaller than EMA, e.g 10% smaller. The percentage of the EMA is the difference I'm looking for.

Same condition for exit price but in reverse, EMA must be bigger than MA and the percentage to exit price from the trade must be 10% larger than the EMA price.

So lets say the `MA50` is `£31000` and the `EMA20` is `£30000`, when the price hits `£27000/10%` less than `EMA`, I want to enter a trade.

And for the exit, `MA50` is `£30000` and the `EMA20` is `£31000`, when the price hits `£34200/10%` greater than `EMA`, I want to exit the trade.

Heres my code so far.... I am new to this so I understand there might still be a lot of work to do. Any help would be appreciated and happy to answer any questions. I have tried to work this out myself but as I am new to coding and trading i seem to be going round in circles. Also have a full time job and 2 young kids so not much time to dedicate to this.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Script", overlay = true)

smaClose = sma(close, 50)
emaClose = ema(close, 20)

strategy.entry("enter long", true, 1, when = close is 10% < emaClose < smaClose)
strategy.close("enter long", when = close is 10% > emaClose > smaClose) 

plot(smaClose, color = color.new(color.yellow, 0), linewidth = 3)
plot(emaClose, color = color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth = 1)
```

I changed the end of my strategy code lines to represent what I want, hoping to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Script", overlay = true)

smaClose = sma(close, 50)
emaClose = ema(close, 20)

entryCondition = close < emaClose*1.1 and  (emaClose < smaClose)

closeCondition = close > (emaClose - (emaClose*0.1))  and  (emaClose > smaClose)


strategy.entry("enter long", strategy.long, 1, when = entryCondition)

strategy.close("enter long",  when = closeCondition) 


plot(smaClose, color = color.new(color.yellow, 0), linewidth = 3)
plot(emaClose, color = color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth = 1)

bgcolor(entryCondition?color.blue:na)
bgcolor(closeCondition?color.purple:na)
```

Comment: Not working as expected im afraid, just enters and exits the trades on one of the first few bars after averages cross, but I really appreciate the help and effort. Feel free to have another go or try the script yourself.